# Implementing a many-to-many LSTM in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

I am using TensorFlow to make predictions on time-series data. So it is like I have 50 tags and I want to find out the next possible 5 tags.

As shown in the following picture, I want to make it like the 4th structure.
[image: RNNs]

I went through the tutorial demo: Recurrent Neural Networks

But I found it can provide like the 5th one in the above picture, which is different.

I am wondering which model could I use? I am thinking of the seq2seq models, but not sure if it is the right way.

Answer (score 8):

You are right that you can use a seq2seq model. For brevity I've written up an example of how you can do it in Keras which also has a Tensorflow backend. I've not run the example so it might need tweaking. If your tags are one-hot you need to use cross-entropy loss instead.

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, RepeatVector

# The input shape is your sequence length and your token embedding size
inputs = Input(shape=(seq_len, embedding_size))

# Build a RNN encoder
encoder = LSTM(128, return_sequences=False)(inputs)

# Repeat the encoding for every input to the decoder
encoding_repeat = RepeatVector(5)(encoder)

# Pass your (5, 128) encoding to the decoder
decoder = LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)(encoding_repeat)

# Output each timestep into a fully connected layer
sequence_prediction = TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='linear'))(decoder)

model = Model(inputs, sequence_prediction)
model.compile('adam', 'mse')  # Or categorical_crossentropy
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Thanks, Simon! 
I did not run the demo of seq2seq. One point that is confusing me is about the embeddings. For the encoder and decoder, I guess I do not need a embedding layer, just pass in my inputs (a list of ids).

Comment: You probably want to embed or one-hot encode your ids. It depends on the nature of your ids but unless you have a very large amount of ids I think one-hot encoding is the right choice. Your data should then be of size `(num_samples, seq_len, one_hot_size)` and you should use cross-entropy loss

Comment: Is it okay to have different size of input and output?

Comment: Because I always get dimension errors, something like "Shapes (50,) and (125,) are not compatible"

Comment: It sounds like you should spend a little more time on the more basic parts. You always need to make sure the input and output dimensions are compatible, both between layers and in the loss function. Your model output i.e. `sequence_prediction` needs to be the same size as your `y_train` in the above model: `y_train.shape = (num_samples, 5, 1)`. Replace the last dimension with your embedding size if you use that, but that should arise naturally from your data.